# Sitecore ErrorManager module - user not logged in on errors pages

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-error-manager

I have such issue while using Sitecore ErrorManager module (https://github.com/unic/SitecoreErrorManager):

When I get custom errors pages in UI (for example, Not Found page or Access Denied page), user is not logged in. Does somebody know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting `ErrorManager.SendClientCookies` in the config of the Error Manager. This is by default set to `false`. When you change this to `true`, all the client cookies (also authentication cookie) should be send and the user should then be logged in also on the error pages.

See more information on the [wiki](https://github.com/unic/SitecoreErrorManager/wiki/Configuration).